# How to deal with does not contain an msbuild solution or packages.config file to restore

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have created one React app with Node JS Backend and Firebase Services. I want to deploy it on Azure platform. I filled basics fields like name of you app, resource group. In deployment I chooses Github and connect Azure to My github repo where my code exist. After that all It shows me Deployment is completed. But in background process Azure is making Actions with github. After 36 seconds my build task failed. So what should i do now? If I am going wrong process then can you suggest me a step wise process to how to deploy

Here error occurred

[image]

In line 20 we can see that content is deleted

[image]

Comment: Then you created a completely wrong manifest for GitHub Actions. Delete the contents in that YAML file and learn how to set up Node.js steps from articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel#javascript

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to share code as text, wit code blocks, and avoid images